# mkdir create a folder in ../ - failed to open stream

Tags: php, mkdir

Folder structure (windows)

```
[root] level 0
      - [lib] level 1
        - core.php
      - [logs] level 1
         -[preg_match number] level 2
          - preg_match number.log
      - [ajax] level 1
         - log_gen.php
      - log_gen_root.php 
[/root]
```

**lib/core.php fragment of the generator**

```
if (preg_match('~\d{24}~', $fname, $m)){
//var_dump($m[1]);
    if (!file_exists('logs/'.$m[0])) {
    mkdir('logs/'.$m[0], 0777, true);
}
}
```

I have located in lib/core.php the mkdir function, the preg_match gets the number ( as $fname ) and returns the number ( as $m[0] ).. There are two options

$fname equal to : variant 1.
First variant is created from the root folder for example log_gen_root.php, everything works here

```
logs/544444466666666666666667/544444466666666666666667.log
```

$fname equal to : variant 2.
The second variant is when I try to access the same mkdir from location ajax/log_gen.php which results in an error. In both cases the log folder is placed in root.

```
../logs/544444466666666666666666/544444466666666666666666.log
```

Warning: file_put_contents(../logs/544444466666666666666666/544444466666666666666666.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\lib\core.php on line 103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things could be happening here:

1. You don't have the correct permissions on the `lib` directory to create a new folder
2. Your path is incorrect.

Try using the below code to grab the directory instead of using relative paths.

```
$folder = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..') . '/lib/';

if (!file_exists($folder . $m[0])) {
    mkdir($folder . $m[0], 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\proj/logs/544444466666666666666666/544444466666666666666666.log): error I got the permissions

Comment: @user3793639 By "I got the permissions", do you mean that you are sure you have the right file permissions setup on the directory tree?

Comment: Yes. The thing is before creating the .log file it creates a directory if not exists. \ / this slashes look wired shouldn't be the same?

Comment: @user3793639 On windows the slashes won't matter.

Comment: @user3793639 The problem is that the folder isn't even being made, correct?

Comment: After debugging :Problem is the preg_match for C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\logs/544444466666666666666666/544444466666666666666666.log) cause it drops no match

Comment: Ok I managed to do it on my own, Lets consider your answer as a help not solution.

Comment: @user3793639 So, what was the solution then?

Comment: Well it was firstly to do the realpath in the files inside ajax folder and change the preg_match regexp ;)